# Updating cursor rects immediately when scrolling stops

Tags: cocoa, scroll

I have a custom view as a documentView of a NSScrollView, which maintains its own cursor rects  with `- (void)resetCursorRects`.

When scrolling the view with mouse wheel (or a trackpad) it takes a while after the scrolling has stopped before Cocoa calls the `- (void)resetCursorRects` method. Looks like it waits for overlay scrollbars to disappear before calling it.

This takes too long, since as a user I can position my mouse to a place where a cursor rect should be before they're updated.

So how can I expedite Cocoa for calling the update method? I could manually call the method, but that is probably not the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Looks like the best way is to use NSTrackingAreas and update the cursor in its - mouseEntered and - mouseExited events.